# Solution of $f(ax+b)=kf(x)$ with $k,a,b$ are real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, functions, functional-equations

I'm interest to know the classification of this functional equation :$f(ax+b)=kf(x)$ with $f$ map $\mathbb{R}$ to $ \mathbb{R}$  ,  and how do i solve it ? with $a, b, k$ are real numbers .

**Note:** we assume $f(0)=0 $

Comment: Can we assume that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: You don't have any additional hypothesis on $f$ ? If not, the set of solutions can be quite huge (for $a = 1$, given *any* function $g : [0,b[ \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $g(0)=0$, $f : x \mapsto g(x) \cdot k^{\lfloor x \rfloor}$ is solution)

Comment: @charMD, what is the classification of this function ?

Comment: @ConnorHarris , No problem if you assume that f is continiuous

Comment: If $a \neq 1$ we have $f\left(\dfrac{a^n - 1}{a - 1} \cdot b\right) = 0$ for any $n \geq 0$. For $a = 1$ we find $f(nb) = 0$ for any $n \geq 0$. Either way, unless $b = 0$ we have an infinite number of zeroes. This rules out many classes of solutions.

Comment: @charMD Are you sure about that? When $a = 1$ we have $f(nb) = 0$, which as far as I can see is not respected for _any_ $g$ in your comment.

Comment: @orlp of course, you're right, the function is not even properly defined ; what I wanted to write was $f : x \mapsto g\big(b \{ \frac{x}{b} \}\big) \cdot k^{\lfloor \frac{x}{b} \rfloor}$ where $\{ . \}$ is the fractional part. Then zeraoulia rafik, I don't really see what you mean by classification of the function, but without any additional hypothesis, for $a = 1, b \neq 0$, there are as many solutions as there are functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (a lot...)